# How to make a pulldown menu display custom meta terms in a theme?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field

I have a pulldown menu in a custom write box that classification numbers. How can I populate a select box on the front end that will:
a) be populated with all the possible values defined in the functions script
b) have the value chosen in wp-admin be selected on page load in the pulldown menu?

This question piggybacks on my [how to add a select menu to a custom meta box](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9779/how-to-add-a-select-menu-to-this-metabox-code) that was answered (perfectly) by בניית אתרים.

My cpt meta box code:

```
function inventory_information() {
    global $post;

    echo '<input type="hidden" name="inventorymeta_noncename" id="inventorymeta_noncename" value="' .
    wp_create_nonce( plugin_basename(__FILE__) ) . '" />';

    $stocknum = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_dappcf_i_stocknum', true);
    $vin = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_dappcf_i_vin', true);
    $my_dropdown = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_dappcf_i_dropdown', true);

    echo '<p>Stock #: <input type="text" name="_dappcf_i_stocknum" value="' . $stocknum  . '" class="widefat" style="width:80px" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
VIN: <input type="text" name="_dappcf_i_vin" value="' . $vin  . '" class="widefat"  style="width:200px" /></p>';

    echo '<p>Inventory class: <select name="_dappcf_i_dropdown" class="widefat">';
    echo '<option value="1"'. $my_dropdown == "1" ? ' selected="selected"' : ''. '>' . 'Option 1'. '</option>';
    echo '<option value="2"'. $my_dropdown == "2" ? ' selected="selected"' : ''. '>' . 'Option 2'. '</option>'; 
    echo '<option value="3"'. $my_dropdown == "3" ? ' selected="selected"' : ''. '>' . 'Option 3'. '</option>'; 
    echo '<option value="4"'. $my_dropdown == "4" ? ' selected="selected"' : ''. '>' . 'Option 4'. '</option>'; 
    echo '</select></p>';
}

function txpbs_save_events_meta($post_id, $post) {
    if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['inventorymeta_noncename'], plugin_basename(__FILE__) )) {
    return $post->ID;
    }
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post->ID ))
return $post->ID;

    $station_meta['_dappcf_i_stocknum'] = $_POST['_dappcf_i_stocknum'];
    $station_meta['_dappcf_i_vin'] = $_POST['_dappcf_i_vin'];
    $station_meta['_dappcf_i_dropdown'] = $_POST['_dappcf_i_dropdown'];

    foreach ($station_meta as $key => $value) {
if( $post->post_type == 'revision' ) return;
$value = implode(',', (array)$value); 
if(get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, FALSE)) {
    update_post_meta($post->ID, $key, $value);
} else {
    add_post_meta($post->ID, $key, $value);
}
if(!$value) delete_post_meta($post->ID, $key);
    }

}
```

And I use this code to call my custom fields when displayed in an input field:

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_dappcf_i_dropdown', true); ?>
```

Any direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does **"be populated with all the possible values defined in the functions script"** mean, where are all these possible values stored?

Comment: It means that the values displayed in the pulldown are displayed on the front end. So `value="1"`, `value="2"`, `value="3"` are shown on the frontend pulldown's options as 1, 2, 3. The frontend should just echo the options that are available in the backend. Does that make sense @t31os ?

Comment: **"the options that are available in the backend."** Yes i understand that part, but where are these options to be pulled from(and based on what?), and is that in your above code?

Comment: @t31os Sorry for the confusion. The code above is my code and that is custom meta field, that is `_dappcf_i_dropdown` is where the options are pulled from.

Comment: You're explicitly setting the possible values in the first function, 1, 2, 3 and 4.. the `_dappcf_i_dropdown` you're referring to is just a custom field name and any references to that name are just fetching a given post's meta value for that key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still not sure what exactly what you aiming for, but having come back to this question i wanted to at least try to offer a solution.

So try this out, and see if that's the kind of thing you had in mind with the dropdown... ?

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_inventory_metaboxes' );
function add_inventory_metaboxes() {
    add_meta_box('inventory_information', 'Inventory Information', 'inventory_information', 'inventory', 'side', 'default');
}

function inventory_dropdown_opts() {
    return array(
        'Option 1' => 1,
        'Option 2' => 2,
        'Option 3' => 3,
        'Option 4' => 4,
    );
}

function inventory_information() {
    global $post;

    $stk_num = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_dappcf_i_stocknum', true );
    $vin_num = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_dappcf_i_vin', true );
    $drp_dwn = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_dappcf_i_dropdown', true );
    if( empty( $drp_dwn ) )
        $drp_dwn = 0;

    wp_nonce_field( 'inventory_nonce', 'inventorymeta_noncename' );
    ?>
    <p>
        <label>Stock #</label> 
        <input type="text" name="_dappcf_i_stocknum" value="<?php echo $stk_num; ?>" class="small-text" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>VIN</label> 
        <input type="text" name="_dappcf_i_vin" value="<?php echo $vin_num; ?>" class="widefat" /></p>
    <p>
        <label>Inventory class</label> 
        <select name="_dappcf_i_dropdown" class="widefat">
        <?php foreach( inventory_dropdown_opts() as $text => $value ) : ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $value; ?>"<?php selected( $value == $drp_dwn ); ?>><?php echo $text; ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
    </p>
    <?php
}

add_action('save_post', 'txpbs_save_events_meta', 1, 2);

function txpbs_save_events_meta( $post_id, $post ) {
    if( 
        !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['inventorymeta_noncename'], 'inventory_nonce' ) || 
        !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) || 
        $post->post_type == 'revision'
        )
        return;

    foreach( array( '_dappcf_i_stocknum', '_dappcf_i_vin', '_dappcf_i_dropdown' ) as $field ) {
        if( isset( $_POST[$field] ) ) {
            if( '_dappcf_i_dropdown' == $field ) {
                if( in_array( $_POST[$field], inventory_dropdown_opts() ) )
                    update_post_meta( $post_id, $field, $_POST[$field] );
                continue;
            }
            update_post_meta( $post_id, $field, $_POST[$field] );
            continue;
        }
        delete_post_meta( $post_id, $key );
    }
}
```

**Follow-up #1**
If you need to show the dropdown in the front end, just do it the same way i did inside the `inventory_information` function, like so..

```
    <select name="add-a-name-here" class="widefat">
    <?php foreach( inventory_dropdown_opts() as $text => $value ) : ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $value; ?>"><?php echo $text; ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
```

Your dropdown options are defined in the `inventory_dropdown_opts` function, so you can use the same both front and admin side, and see the same data.

Comment: I appreciate your time in helping solve this. As you said there is some confusion for what I was trying to accomplish so for that I apologize. I'm trying to display the pulldown variables in the custom meta field on the frontend, so in single-inventory.php as a pulldown menu. So if the pulldown in wp-admin is for option 1, 2, 3, 4 the pulldown on the front is for option 1, 2, 3, 4. I hope this clarifies things.  :)

Comment: Have updated my answer. :)

Comment: Awesome. Thanks @t31os for your help, I was really really getting stuck on this.  :)